# How to vary matrix of matrices in a loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

In my program i have got the value of

```
RpMats{k} = Rp;
```

Where RpMats is an array of matrices and each element of RpMats is 50x50 matrix. Example: RpMats = [(50x50 matrix) (50x50 matrix) (50x50 matrix) (50x50 matrix) .... (50x50 matrix)] I have total 100 matrices in RpMats. I want to use these elements of RpMats (which are matrix) in the below loop:

```
for j = 1 : 50
X = max( Rp(j,:)-RecPackets, 0) ; 
end
```

% here Rp is the input of first element of RpMats, then second element of RpMats like this. Which means by mentioning Rp i want to provide input from the RpMats. first input of Rp will be the first matrix of RpMats Like this i want to give all the 100 matrix of RpMats as input to Rp. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you be more clear?

Comment: RpMats is an array which has 100 matrices in that array like RpMats=[[50x50 matrix with one and zero] [50x50 matrix with one and zero] [50x50 matrix with one and zero] [50x50 matrix with one and zero] ..... [50x50 matrix with one and zero] ] which i have got from the loop below:

Comment: updated my problem. please check now.

Comment: If all Rp matrices are of same size, you can build RpMats as a 3D array and not an array of cells. It may be more practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need two indices. One to specify which matrix of your array you want to adress, lets call that index `jj`. And further the index which adresses the element of each matrix, e.g. `ii`.

Then you can create (for example) a nested loop:

```
for jj=1:number of matrices in array
    for ii=1:50
        Rp{jj}(ii,:) = do something
    end
end
```

So cell arrays (what your matrix array is) are adressed with `{...}` returning a matrix of doubles and this matrix is then adressed with `(...)`.

If you want to use something like Rp{jj,:} - I'd recommend `{Rp{jj,:}}` (for example when you have a matrix of matrices but you're just interested in a certain column, you could filter it like that.